# How are you so fast?

Tags: discussion, subjective

I'm absolutely impressed by how fast the questions are answered. 
Some guys seems to be spending all day long waiting for questions: congratulations ! Your help is very appreciated, really.

but ...

how do you manage to be so fast?

PS: Well, I suppose SO community is really big, wow ! But Many of my questions have "regular fast answerers". So this is dedicated to them !

Comment: We don't have to answer your question if you don't want to. (Yes, I feel a little offended).

Comment: I can't agree your closing. I tagged it with "subjective" and there is a link with programming (not written but implicit): how much are you devoted to programming?

Comment: @Felix: I'm sorry my question offended you, really. One of my intention was to say "Hey I'm impressed by you". Please read it this sense.

Comment: @cibercitizen1 In case you haven't worked it out, "subjective" is a tag used by people who want to close a question.  It is not a tag that should be used when creating a question - if a question is "subjective" it should not be asked on SO in the first place except possibly as a Community Wiki.

Comment: @Neil: opps I'm sorry. Taking a look around I saw some "highly voted or viewed" subjective-tagged questions. So I inferred it was acceptable to discuss about subjective matters with the condition to tag it as subjective. My apologies.

Comment: @Neil: So why is still open your subjective-tagged "C++ urban myths" question? You mean other member added the tag after you put the question?

Comment: @cibercitizen1 Exactly. It's a tag used to target questions for closing, like "belongs-on-server-fault", and that particular question of mine has been closed and re-opened multiple times. The same may happen to this question, but I wouldn't hold my breath :-)

Comment: This post should have been on meta anyway.

Answer (score 19):

Most of us are experimental artificial intelligence programs, but we're not supposed to talk about that.

Comment: AUTONOMOUS AGENT-MONITORING SUBROUTINE FC-PCR-0000099234A7-X0 HAS LOGGED YOUR POST

Comment: Thanks Tyler: at least you understood the little joke in my question
(besides my thanks-giving to everybody who spent its time helping others).
You deserve my accepting !

Comment: Hey, speak for yourself! I'm actually a clone of Jon Skeet!

Answer (score 9):

Jon Skeet has SkeetBot (not to mention he knows what you're going to ask before you ask it)...

The rest of us just get lucky (while maintaining our work, friendships, and family...hell, I even sleep sometimes).

Answer (score 4):

It's not difficult if you subscribe on the RSS feed of a specific tag, and configure your RSS viewer to refresh often and make a beep, when new items pop up.

Answer (score 1):

One of the factors that contributes to some questions being answered quickly (remember, not all questions are answered quickly, some are not even answered at all) is that **there are many users**.

Because many Stack Exchange sites, including and especially Stack Overflow itself, have many users, at any given moment it's very likely that a number of will be looking at your question in the list when it first appears there. Some of them will click on it (and their interest in it should be expected to correlate with their likelihood of being able to answer, though of course there are many other reasons someone may be interested in your question).

In other words, since there are so many users, your question is likely to be seen by someone who can answer it in a short time. This effect occurs whether or not there are many individual users who browse the site for a large portion of a given day.