# Could the Stack Exchange sites use IBM Watson to answer questions?

Tags: discussion

Watching [Watson](http://www-03.ibm.com/innovation/us/watson/) compete against Ken Jennings on [Jeopardy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLR1byL0U8M) showed what a next-gen knowledge repository should be.  Imagine Watson on the Stack Exchange sites providing answers even quicker than the community currently does.  Plus [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) would finally have some competition.

Comment: What would Watson provide that isn't already provided by search engines?

Comment: <rings buzzer> What is Potato Salad?

Comment: I have no doubt in my mind that the information I require when I ask a question on a Stack Exchange site is already out there on the Internet somewhere, but for whatever reason I have been unable to find said information, thus I post a question. From what I saw on Jeopardy it seems Watson can make more intelligible decisions than your standard search engine.

Comment: I want to see Watson answer a "HULLO I WANT TO MAKE A SOCIAL NETWORKING SITE USING JQUERY PLEASE SUGGEST" question.

Comment: <rings buzzer> What is using jQuery and red freehand circles to make waffles for unicorns and Jon Skeet, on Fridays in Iceland, in 6 to 8 weeks, on a boat, as a programmer?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103919/why-are-answers-on-stack-overflow-so-fast/103927#103927

Comment: It has already [been done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert)

Answer (score 8):

The problem with Watson and answering Jeopardy questions is that the answers on Jeopardy tend to be really short simple answers, whereas the best questions on Stack Exchange tend to have lengthy answers. (And yes, I do know that Jeopardy uses answers to get a question, but...) Getting a coherent document assembled is rather difficult to do completely by a machine today. The best I can see is a script to automatically quote Wikipedia, which wouldn't be the best thing, or a search engine, which also has it's challenges.

However, I don't doubt that some day we will be able to have do such a thing, but humans are required for some of the work here on Stack Exchange, for the foreseeable future.

Comment: [<Innocent whistling sound goes here>](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/)

Answer (score 5):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/211627) --

> "ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T A**LL I​S L**OST th*e pon̷y he come*s he c̶̮om<strike>es he co</strike>**<strike>me</strike>s t*he* ich​**or permeat*es al*l MY FAC*E MY FACE ᵒh god n**o NO NOO̼*****O​O N**Θ stop t*he an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨ*e̠̅s `͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e` n**​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ T**O͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘**Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝**S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex+html) --

> "How do I parse this bit of HTML using regex?"

Comment: That looks right. Thanks! :trollface: